# returning a value from .getAttribute while inside spec

Tags: xpath, protractor

I have a function inside a pageObject class :

```
async getSingleIdFromDrawerUsing(test1, test2) {
    await browser.wait(async () => {
      return await element(by.xpath('//h3[.="' + test1 + '"]/..' +
        '//something//div[@attr1"' + test2 + '"]')).getAttribute('attr2')
        .then(async (value) => {
          const item = value;
          console.log(item);
          return await item;
      });
    });
  }
```

this function works perfectly from what i can tell from the console.log however when I am inside the spec file calling it I get undefined.

here is my spec and what I am doing:

```
it('should click into widget from drawer and verify URL has correct Id', async () => {
    const actualReportId = await pagePbject.getSingleIdFromDrawerUsing('test1', 'test2');
    console.log(actualReportId);
    await pagePbject.clickIntoIdFromDrawer('test1', 'test2');
    expect(await browser.getCurrentUrl()).toBe(pagePbject.routeUrl + actualReportId);
});
```

here is my output from the spec run:

```
spits out correct Id from console.log inside the pageObject class
undefined (this is from the spec)
    × should click into test1 test2 widget from the drawer
      - Expected 'http://localhost:49158/url/id' to be 'http://localhost:49158/url/undefined'.
```

I have to be doing something wrong but i cant figure it out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure why you even need `browser.wait()` in your function. You should just be able to do this:

```
async getSingleIdFromDrawerUsing(test1, test2) {
    return element(by.xpath('//h3[.="' + test1 + '"]/..' +
        '//something//div[@attr1"' + test2 + '"]')).getAttribute('attr2');
}
```

If that doesn't work you can just resolve a native Promise:

```
getSingleIdFromDrawerUsing(test1, test2) {
    return new Promise(resolve => {
        element(by.xpath('//h3[.="' + test1 + '"]/..' +
            '//something//div[@attr1"' + test2 + '"]')).getAttribute('attr2')
            .then(value => {
                resolve(value);
            }
    }
}
```

You would call it the same way in both examples:

```
const actualReportId = await pageObject.getSingleIdFromDrawerUsing('test1', 'test2');
```